# Calculating work using dot product in C++

Tags: c++, array, homework, calculator, physics

> Write a C++ program fulfilling the following task: The user should enter the 3 dimensional force vector F and a 3 dimensional length vector s. The force is assumed to be constant. The program then calculates the work W = F (dot) s and prints the result on the screen.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //I decided to try and declare my variables locally to make it easier for readers.
    double F[3];
    int i;

    cout << "Enter in components of the force vector F:\n";

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Component " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> F[i];

    }

    double s[3];

    cout << "Enter in the components of the length vector s:\n";

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Component " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> s[i];
    }

    double W = 0.0;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
       W = W + (F[i] * s[i]);
    }

    cout << "The work done is: " << W << " J";

    return 0;
}
```

Does "The force is assumed to be constant" change anything about the code. I don't see how that makes a difference? Is it included for completeness?

Comment: `Does "The force is assumed to be constant" change anything about the code.` Yes and no. It simplifies the assignment, so your code doesn't have to be more complex than it currently is. Although there's a lot of code duplication going on that's not necessary. Is this a [tag:homework] assignment?

Comment: It is - I added the tag there. If the force wasn't constant I'd have to use a line intergral right? "Duplication" - Do you mean when I ask the user to input a vector?

Comment: Yes on both occasions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `using namespace std` should be avoided

Not much more to say than that. Just don't do it. The worst case is putting it into a header. Next is using it outside any namespace, so you've done the second worst possible incarnation of this particular problem.

Typing `std::cout` instead of `cout` really isn't going to cause you a lot of problem, I promise.

#### Don't Repeat Yourself

You have essentially identical code for entering the two input vectors. You probably want to use a function to enter the values for a vector, and just call it once for each input vector.

#### Use the Library

As a general rule, I'd avoid using built-in arrays when at all reasonable. In this case, you can use `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<double, 3> F;
std::array<double, 3> s;
```

The standard library already provides `std::inner_product` to do exactly the calculation you're doing. You might as well use it:

```
double W = std::inner_product(F.begin(), F.end(), s.begin(), 0.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using C++, why don't you create a vector class? Using an array of 3 `double`s is problematic because it doesn't tell the compiler or a reader what the array represents. It also doesn't allow you to simplify your code the way a class would. If you had a `vector3` class, for example, you could have a method that takes the dot product of itself and another vector. You might implement it like this:

```
class vector3 {
    public:
        vector3(double newX, double newY, double newZ) : x(newX), y(newY), z(newZ) {}
        ~vector3() {}

        double dot(const vector3& other)
        {
            return x * other.x + y * other.y + z * other.z;
        }

    private:
        double x { 0.0 };
        double y { 0.0 };
        double z { 0.0 };
};
```

It's a lot more clear why you're multiplying and adding numbers when you can write:

```
vector3 v(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
vector3 w(3.0, 2.0, 1.0);
double result = v.dot(w);
```

If it's just 2 arrays, who knows what the values in them represent?

This will also allow you to expand the class in the future to add other functions a vector needs such as adding and subtracting other vectors.

Answer (score 1):

When you write C++, don't declare variables as soon as possible. Your comment says this improves readability, but it actually has the *opposite* effect. All variables should be declared as late as possible, and as locally as possible.

This makes it easier to absorb the part of code you are reading, and possibly has a small impact on performance as well (e.g., maybe you never execute the part that needs certain variables that you have defined in the beginning of your function).

So just do `for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)` instead of `for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)`, where `i` is declared god knows where.